# How to add ajax pagination?

Tags: php, ajax, database, pagination

I am using this 
[PHP Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp) example from w3schools.This is working fine but it's not an efficient solution when the record list will be huge.So i want to add pagination  to handle large records.How can i add pagination (Ajax pagination so that i can avoid page reloading) with this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE type_no = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use `LIMIT` to add in a start row and a length, so `LIMIT 10,10` will give you records 10 to 19. You will need to pass a page number or a start value via a query string value. There are loads of examples in this site (see the 'pagination' tag) and elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is use the `LIMIT` feature in mysql. When I look at your example I would assume that the sql statement would only return one result.

Lets assume you had a table called `user` with many users if you had a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

You would get all the users back in one query. This is not practical for most uses. The most elegant solution in my opinion is the `LIMIT` feature.

For example if I wanted to see results in a range:

```
SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 0,50   #return first 50 results - records 0 to 49

SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 50,50  #return the next 50 results - records 50 to 99
```

`LIMIT` syntax looks like this `LIMIT <offset>,<count>` Where offset is the starting result (starts at 0) and count is the number of results you want back.

So lets assume you had pages size of 50 and and were on the 5th page you would want:

```
LIMIT 100,25
```

Handling this at the database level is the simplest and quickest method.

Comment: No it will return result according to where clause.so the  list may be large .However i have updated my post and query.